# Ruby on Rails: Getting validates_uniqueness_of to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two params :work and :grade. In the model, before saving I want to use validates_uniqueness_of to check given a unique work, there is only one grade. Grade can be the same for other work. How would I write this?

Edit:

validates_uniqueness_of :work, :scope => :grade

Comment: posting the code for your models would be beneficial for answering this question.

Comment: What does the stated code __not__ do that you would like it to do?

Comment: If i create work: "Test" and grade: 77, it won't work if I create work "Test 2" and grade: 77

Comment: You have a typo, you need an extra `s` in `uniqueness`

Comment: The typo isn't my issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a deprecated syntax warning, you can write it so:

```
validates :work, uniqueness: {scope: :grade}, presence: true
```

Edit:

It seems you need a two way checking, so perhaps adding this will work:

```
validates :grade, uniqueness: {scope: :work}, presence: true
```

Although under high load I've seen this fail, so best is to create a database constraint.

Comment: I don't get a deprecated syntax warning. It's not working for me for the case:  work: "Test" and grade: 77, it won't work if I create work "Test 2" and grade: 77

Comment: @Julia can you try adding the constraint both ways like I showed?